# Want to be able to collect metrics of latency and response time over time

Tags: jmeter, latency, throughput

I performing login into my web application using JMeter,

I want to measure latency and response time but not in a single run I want to be able to run it once in a hour and create a graph with results which will sum the results (let's say of 4-5 runs) and display the latency and response time for all the runs.

I already wrote a JMeter script which perform browsing to login page and performing the actual login.

I have no problem of displaying my results but I want to be able to display results of **several run executions** over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JMeter plugin [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) to display more then one result file:

[image]